# Converting this simple Javascript into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

```
var b=new Array(102,50,57,101,52,55,53,54,49,57,55,97,100,55,52,99,48,56,53,100,55,97,98,53,101,101,102,100,49,49,101,54,50,97,100,48,97,101,49,52,38,104,61,50,52,61,56,55,101,99,102,110,111,51,55,78,109,114,111,57,101,54,102,51,101,38,101,56,54,56,53,53,54,54,53,51,56,102,57,54,52,61,100,101,50,57,49,99,105,50,102,95,116,54,102,101,115,51,105,100,48,108,116,57,105,104,54,63,48,112,104,112,48,46,121,116,110,117,111,98);
var p=new Array(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);         
function c(b,p) {
    a='';s=String.fromCharCode;
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++) {if(p[i])a=s(b[i])+a;else a+=s(b[i]);}
    return a;
}
```

I am trying to convert the above JavaScript code to PHP, but because in some ways it is compressed to make it more confusing, I'm having great difficulty. Your help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: This is what I've tried:

```
<?php
          $b=array(102,50,57,101,52,55,53,54,49,57,55,97,100,55,52,99,48,56,53,100,55,97,98,53,101,101,102,100,49,49,101,54,50,97,100,48,97,101,49,52,38,104,61,50,52,61,56,55,101,99,102,110,111,51,55,78,109,114,111,57,101,54,102,51,101,38,101,56,54,56,53,53,54,54,53,51,56,102,57,54,52,61,100,101,50,57,49,99,105,50,102,95,116,54,102,101,115,51,105,100,48,108,116,57,105,104,54,63,48,112,104,112,48,46,121,116,110,117,111,98);
          $p=array(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);     
$a='';
class String {
    public static function fromCharCode() {
        return array_reduce(func_get_args(),function($d,$e){$d.=chr($e);return $d;});
    }
}
for($i=0;$i<b.length;$i++) {if($p[$i])$a=String::fromCharCode($b[$i]) . $a;else $a+=String::fromCharCode($b[$i]);}
echo $a; ?>
```

It returns blank.

How do I convert this simple Javascript into PHP?

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: I'm no expert in javascript, but shouldn't there be some variable fed into your `fromCharCode` method? Also, do you mind explaining what `if(p[i])a=s(b[i])+a;else a+=s(b[i]);` does?

Comment: @Huey yes. It's an array. I'll provide it in the answer. Additionally, I don't know what it makes a link to a web page.

Comment: I believe you can replace the `fromCharCode()` method with PHP's `chr()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it it's to use [chr](http://pt2.php.net/chr).

> chr — Return a specific character

```
$b = array(102,50,57,101,52,55,53,54,49,57,55,97,100,55,52,99,48,56,53,100,55,97,98,53,101,101,102,100,49,49,101,54,50,97,100,48,97,101,49,52,38,104,61,50,52,61,56,55,101,99,102,110,111,51,55,78,109,114,111,57,101,54,102,51,101,38,101,56,54,56,53,53,54,54,53,51,56,102,57,54,52,61,100,101,50,57,49,99,105,50,102,95,116,54,102,101,115,51,105,100,48,108,116,57,105,104,54,63,48,112,104,112,48,46,121,116,110,117,111,98);
$p = array(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);         

function c($b,$p) {
    $a='';
    for($i=0;$i<count($b);$i++){
        if($p[$i]){
            $a=chr($b[$i]) . $a;
        }else{
            $a.=chr($b[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $a;
}

echo(c($b,$p));
```

OUTPUT

```
bounty.php?hitlist_id=9366558&formNonce=e0d2fe5b7d80c47a1654f29e797d5aed11e6aa14&h=2487f379e63ee6858f64e291c2f6fe3d09600
```

Both examples in JS and PHP same output.

working example php: [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fKawu2)

working example js: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ9Pm/)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. Just a literal translation

```
function c($b, $p){
 $a="";
 for ($i=0;$i<strlen($b);$i++){
   if ($p[$i]) $a=chr($b[$i]).$a; else $a.=chr($b[$i]);
 }
 return $a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

```
function c($b,$p){
    $a = '';
    $s = chr();
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($b);$i++){
        if($p[$i]){
            $a = chr($b[$i]).$a;
        } else {
            $a .= chr($b[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Note: you ought to give your variables more descriptive names

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I used for this kind of hack was to dynamically write javascript script by PHP but echoing it out via http header with content-type identifier.  See below as an example:

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.php"></script>
```

js.php

```
<?php
$js = <<<JS
///BEGIN JS SCRIPT //
var b=new Array(102,50,57,101,52,55,53,54,49,57,55,97,100,55,52,99,48,56,53,100,55,97,98,53,101,101,102,100,49,49,101,54,50,97,100,48,97,101,49,52,38,104,61,50,52,61,56,55,101,99,102,110,111,51,55,78,109,114,111,57,101,54,102,51,101,38,101,56,54,56,53,53,54,54,53,51,56,102,57,54,52,61,100,101,50,57,49,99,105,50,102,95,116,54,102,101,115,51,105,100,48,108,116,57,105,104,54,63,48,112,104,112,48,46,121,116,110,117,111,98);

var p=new Array(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);

function c(b,p) {
a='';
s=String.fromCharCode;
for(i=0;i<b.length;i++) {if(p[i])a=s(b[i])+a;else a+=s(b[i]);}
return a;
}

/// END JS SCRIPT //
JS;
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
echo $js;
exit();
?>
```

One setback I found about this approach is that the script can't be cached if you want to re-access to these variables in later lines of scripts from your html.  But, it serves as a great benefit for some implementation of my work "behind the scene".